# How do I fix dual boot startup for Ubuntu installation on Windows 8 Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub, multi-boot, uefi

I have a Lenovo laptop with preinstalled windows 8 64bit- I did an installation of Ubuntu 13.04 - however after installation I was faced with the GRUB loader. From the Grub loader if I try to start up the Windows Loader option it wouldnt load windows 8 and instead show me an EFI file missing error.

Alternatively if I restart the laptop and click F12 key I get to the Bootloader screen where I can choose to boot either:

- Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Loader
- EFI DVD/CD ROM
- EFI USB

This is pretty much the only way I can choose to enter into either windows or Ubuntu plus after installing Ubuntu I've noticed that I now have a new unrecognised file format partition on windows 8 - I'm assuming its the Ubuntu partition.

The question is that how can I set up a dual boot screen that actually works here so I can choose to boot either windows 8 or Ubuntu?

Comment: It's not quite the same question, but see my answer to [this question.](http://superuser.com/questions/550643/restore-windows-8-efi-after-installing-ubuntu-efi)

Comment: Hmmmmactually the problem here is that I can boot into both but only if I push F12 and manually select from the bios screen - I want to be able to choose between either ubuntu and windows 8 from a simple dual boot screen - whether it be via windows boot loader or even GRUB.

Comment: The screen you get when you hit F12 is the computer's built-in boot manager, but AFAIK, few or no EFIs provide an option to launch it by default. Thus, you must rely on another boot manager (such as GRUB or rEFInd) to do the OS-switching if you want such an option by default on every boot. Currently, your GRUB is launching but isn't booting Windows. Boot Repair (option #1 in my linked-to answer) will probably fix that. Alternatively, installing rEFInd (option #2) as the default boot manager will fix the problem in another way. (rEFInd is more reliable at launching Windows than is GRUB.)